# Finding concentration of hydronium ions in water after adding hydrogen chloride gas

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws, concentration

> A sample of hydrogen chloride gas, $\ce{HCl}$, occupies $\pu{0.932 l}$ at a pressure $\pu{1.44 bar}$ and at a temperature of $\pu{50^\circ C}$. The sample is dissolved in $\pu{1 l}$ of water.
> What is the resulting hydronium ion ($\ce{H3O+}$) concentration?
>
> Ammonia gas also dissolved quantitatively in water.
> If it is measured at $\pu{0.720 bar}$ and $\pu{50^\circ C}$, what volume of $\ce{NH3}$ gas is required to neutralize the solution prepared in the above question?
>
> For present purposes, assume that the neutralization  reaction occurs quantitatively.

**My attempt**:

$\pu{0.05 mol}$ of $\ce{HCl}$ is dissolved in the $\pu{55.55 mol}$ of water. Balancing equation is

$$\ce{HCl(g) + H2O(l) <=> H3O+ + Cl-(aq)}$$

Is there a mistake in this assumption? I ask this because I am unable to proceed further.

Comment: Did you forget to complete the attempt, or is this it?

Comment: @Safdar, I didn't forget to complete the attempt. I just don't have any idea to proceed further. I know molarity formula, but i am doubtful about its usefulness here.

Comment: I've removed the second part of your question since it is basically the same thing but using $\ce{OH-}$ instead.. Also, HCl is a **strong electrolyte**. Does this help?

Comment: @Safdar, I think the second part is required because the author is asking what volume of ammonia gas $\ce{NH3}$ is necessary to neutralize the solution created in first part.

Comment: Is there a reason to suppose you get negatively charged gas consisting of chloride ions, while solution would be charged positively ? BTW, I replaced the character you have used by the regular minus to be displayed properly.

Comment: For the task purpose, you need not to work with water molar mass nor molar amount of 1 L of water.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You correctly found that amount of $\ce{HCl}$ gas in the container is $\pu{0.05 mol}$. When it dissolves in $\pu{1.0 L}$ of water you get $\pu{0.05 M}$ $\ce{HCl}$ solution. Does it matter for this calculations? No, but I did it anyway. However, it gives us very important information. $\ce{HCl}$ is a strong electrolyte and it dissolves in water as high as $\pu{12 M}$. When dissolve in water, it completely dissociates:

$$\ce{HCl (g) + H2O (l) -> H3O+ (aq) + Cl- (aq)} \tag1$$

For the second part of the question, you need to know what is the reaction between $\ce{HCl}$ and $\ce{HH3}$:

$$\ce{HCl (aq) + NH3 (aq) -> NH4Cl (aq) -> NH4+ (aq) + Cl- (aq)} \tag2$$

Thus, mol% of the reaction is $1:1$. Therefore, the amount of $\ce{HH3 (g)}$ you need to complete neutralization is the amount of $\ce{HCl}$ in the solution, which is $\pu{0.05 mol}$. Now, you can use ideal gal law to calculate the $V$ under given conditions.

---

**Note:** Ammonia in water is in equilibrium with:
$$\ce{NH3 (g) + H2O (l) <=> NH4+ (aq) + OH- (aq)} \tag3$$
The complete nutralization is the reactions of $(1)$ and $(3)$ where net ionic reaction is:
$$\ce{H3O+ (aq) + OH- (aq) -> 2 H2O (l)} \tag4$$

However, since $\ce{NH3}$ is a weak base, its conjgate acid $\ce{NH4+}$ is acidic. Therefore, this titration would not pass $\mathrm{pH = 7}$ mark at the end point (thus need an appropriate indicator).

Comment: So, the concentration of $\ce{H3O+}$ in the solution of HCL created in first part is $\pu{0.05 mol l^{-1}}$. Isn't it?

Comment: That is the key ($\ce{H+ + H2O -> H3O+}$).

Comment: Sorry, I am beginner in chemistry study. So i don't know what is $\ce{HH3}$ and $\ce{HH4+}$? Would you tell me?

Comment: See equation (3) under notes (similar to $\ce{H2O}$ and $\ce{H3O+}$).

Comment: So, the volume of ammonia gas $\ce{NH3}$ required to neutralize the solution prepared in the first part at 0.720 bar and $50^\circ C$ is 1.866 liters. Isn't it?

Comment: That is correct. Best way to do word problem is better understanding of the problem and try what you can do with the date with your knowledge of chemistry. Good luck!